# Remove arraylist element

Tags: java, arraylist

I have two arraylist fileWordList and stopWordList. I want to compare fileWordList to stopWordList and delete any same words from fileWordList. My codes are as below:

```
ArrayList<String> fileWordList = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> stopWordList = new ArrayList<String>();

for (Iterator<String> i = fileWordList.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {

    for(Iterator<String> j = stopWordList.iterator(); j.hasNext();){
        if (j.next() == i.next()){
           i.remove();
        }
    }

}
```

The error was caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException. How to solve this? What is wrong with the code?

Comment: What do you mean by "similar"? Can you give an example of words that you consider to be similar, but which would not compare equal?

Comment: Consider using `Set` instead of `List` for large collections. Then you could do: `fileWordSet.removeAll(stopWordSet)`. This would also take care of multiple occurences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling `i.next()` too many times. You should call it once per iteration of the outer loop and remember the result.

```
for (Iterator<String> i = fileWordList.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
    String s = i.next();
    for(Iterator<String> j = stopWordList.iterator(); j.hasNext();){
        if (j.next() == s){ // consider using equals here
           i.remove();
           break; // No need to continue checking.
        }
    }

}
```

I suspect that you want to use `j.next().equals(s)` to compare two strings for equality.

You may also want to consider using `ArrayList.contains`. Or use a [`HashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) to store your stop words, as you probably don't care about the order in which they are stored.

Comment: You are better off using the for-each syntax.

Comment: if ArrayList.contains is used, does it means I don't have to iterate the list? and how do I know which element to remove?

Comment: Using `ArrayList.contains(Object o)` means you don't have to iterate it yourself.  When you call `i.remove` it will remove the the element `i.next()` returned.  That's why you have an `if` statement to check if it is in the list.  Also as @Havard suggested, it's much simpler to use a `for each` loop`.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the ArrayList `contains()` method instead of nested loop?

```
for (Iterator<String> i = fileWordList.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {

    String word = i.next();

    // Only removes first occurence.
    if (stopWordList.contains(word)) {
        i.remove();
    }
}

// Better and simpler solution
for (String word : stopWordList) {
    while(fileWordList.contains(word)) {
        fileWordList.remove(word);
    }
}
```

Comment: this one is good and precise but it doesn't consider words starting with uppercase. is there a way for that?

Comment: The string class has a special method for that. [String#equalsIgnoreCase(String anotherString)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String))

Comment: @mellissa Edit:  Actually, that didn't seem to work. Havard's suggestion should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(String word : stopWordList) 
    if(fileWordList.contains(word)) 
        fileWordList.remove(word)
```

Comment: hm, i didn't cover multiple occurances of word in the file.